# How can use input search box in select in js?

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to make a search input search in select options, but the code is not finding the text.
How can change code to fix this? See snippet below.

```js
searchBox = document.querySelector("#searchBox");
countries = document.querySelector("#countries");
var when = "keyup"; //You can change this to keydown, keypress or change

searchBox.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    var text = e.target.value; //searchBox value
    var options = countries.options; //select options
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var option = options[i]; //current option
        var optionText = option.text; //option text ("Somalia")
        var lowerOptionText = optionText.toLowerCase(); //option text lowercased for case insensitive testing
        var lowerText = text.toLowerCase(); //searchBox value lowercased for case insensitive testing
        var regex = new RegExp("^" + text, "i"); //regExp, explained in post
        var match = optionText.match(regex); //test if regExp is true
        var contains = lowerOptionText.indexOf(lowerText) != -1; //test if searchBox value is contained by the option text
        if (match || contains) { //if one or the other goes through
            option.selected = true; //select that option
            return; //prevent other code inside this event from executing
        }
        searchBox.selectedIndex = 0; //if nothing matches it selects the default option
    }
});
```

```html
    <input type="search" id="searchBox">
    <select id="countries">
        <option value="arg">Argentina</option>
        <option value="usa">United States of America</option>
        <option value="som">Somalia</option>
    </select>
```

This code outside works in the input search box in js so I try but do not achieve inside input search box in select.

I want to be able to either type in the text field above the box or just click on the option directly.

What would be the best way to go about that? Is there anything bootstrap related that exists already?

Comment: Why is this tagged React?

Comment: I am not using tagged react. This link you will be understand https://codepen.io/ankit3131/pen/abYLGpV

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. I removed the React tag because I don't see React anywhere here. Ditto jQuery.

Comment: Hi  I made your code a running snippet (the `<>` button). The search seems to work on its own. Maybe you have unrelated errors in your browser console that you have to fix first.